# Running Jar File from Java Program

Tags: java, jar, processbuilder

I am trying to run a `.jar` from within my `Java` program. I am using `ProcessBuilder` to do so, but it is not working correctly.

I am wondering if I am missing something.

This is what I currently have that is trying to run the `.jar`

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/JARFile/JARFile.jar");
Process p = pb.start();
```

I have the directory correct, so I am not positive why this is not working properly.

Do I have something wrong with my parameters in the `new ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Try `\\JARFile\\JARFile.jar` instead of `/JARFile/JARFile.jar`

Comment: @Vebbie that did not work either

Answer (score 0):

1) in third argument set full path to file:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar",
            "/home/meiskalt7/Documents/runJar-55056616-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
```

Result will be look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar",
            "/home/meiskalt7/Documents/runJar-55056616-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
            .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
}
```

and in console you will see result of execution

2) If everything will be good then you must check your system property with

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"))
```

and if path looks like path in first step then you must compare path with equals operator:

```
System.out.println((System.getProperty("user.home") + "/JARFile/JARFile.jar")
                                                      .equals([YOUR FULL PATH]))
```

Maybe your problem with symbols of another language in path

2*) if something go wrong then you can check error of process execution in error stream of your process:

```
InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
        System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(err))
                .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```